# Client host rejected in postfix port 587

Tags: postfix, sasl

```
In master.cf:
127.0.0.1:587     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o cleanup_service_name=subcleanup
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

It is repeated for other IPs of eth0 interface.

```
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 32 flush 54
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 32 got 17
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: status
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: 0
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: rate
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: rate
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: 1
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: (end)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: extract_addr: input: <email@domenadotestumaila.tk>
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: connect to subsystem private/rewrite
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: event_enable_read: fd 35
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: event_request_timer: set 0x7ff801f6f440 0x55f7fea0b800 5
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: event_request_timer: set 0x7ff801f6f420 0x55f7fea0b800 1000
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr request = rewrite
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr rule = local
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr address = ""
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 35 flush 39
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 35 got 20
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: 0
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: address
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: ""
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: (end)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: rewrite_clnt: local: "" -> ""
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: event_request_timer: reset 0x7ff801f6f440 0x55f7fea0b800 5
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr request = rewrite
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr rule = local
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr address = email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 35 flush 64
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 35 got 45
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: 0
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: address
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: address
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: (end)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: rewrite_clnt: local: email@testdomain.example.net -> email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: event_request_timer: reset 0x7ff801f6f440 0x55f7fea0b800 5
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr request = resolve
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr sender =
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr address = email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 35 flush 61
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 35 got 107
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: 0
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: transport
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: transport
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: lmtp
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: nexthop
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: nexthop
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: recipient
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: recipient
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: 1024
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: (end)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: resolve_clnt: `' -> `email@testdomain.example.net' -> transp=`lmtp' host=`unix:private/dovecot-lmtp' rcpt=`email@testdomain.example.net' flags= class=virtual
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: ctable_locate: install entry key ?email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: extract_addr: in: <email@testdomain.example.net>, result: email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: report sender to all milters
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter_macro_lookup: "i"
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter_macro_lookup: "{auth_type}"
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter_macro_lookup: "{auth_authen}"
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter_macro_lookup: "{auth_author}"
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter_macro_lookup: "{mail_addr}"
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key ?email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter_macro_lookup: result "email@testdomain.example.net"
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter_macro_lookup: "{mail_host}"
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key ?email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter_macro_lookup: result "unix:private/dovecot-lmtp"
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter_macro_lookup: "{mail_mailer}"
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key ?email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter_macro_lookup: result "lmtp"
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: milter8_mail_event: milter unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: mail <email@testdomain.example.net> SIZE=406
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 31 flush 230
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 31 got 5
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: reply: SMFIR_CONTINUE data 0 bytes
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: smtpd_check_rewrite: trying: permit_inet_interfaces
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: permit_inet_interfaces: 178-36-39-54.adsl.inetia.pl 178.36.39.54
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: fsspace: .: block size 4096, blocks free 65435210
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: smtpd_check_queue: blocks 4096 avail 65435210 min_free 0 msg_size_limit 36000000
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: > 178-36-39-54.adsl.inetia.pl[178.36.39.54]: 250 2.1.0 Ok
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: watchdog_pat: 0x55f7fe9fe140
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: < 178-36-39-54.adsl.inetia.pl[178.36.39.54]: RCPT TO:<example@example.com> ORCPT=rfc822;example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: extract_addr: input: <example@example.com>
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: rewrite_clnt: cached: local: email@testdomain.example.net -> email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: event_request_timer: reset 0x7ff801f6f440 0x55f7fea0b800 5
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr request = rewrite
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr rule = local
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr address = example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 35 flush 57
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 35 got 38
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: 0
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: address
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: (end)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: rewrite_clnt: local: example@example.com -> example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: event_request_timer: reset 0x7ff801f6f440 0x55f7fea0b800 5
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr request = resolve
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr sender = email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr address = example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 35 flush 81
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 35 got 85
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: 0
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: transport
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: transport
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: panel
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: nexthop
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: nexthop
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: recipient
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: recipient
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: rewrite_clnt: local: example@example.com -> example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: event_request_timer: reset 0x7ff801f6f440 0x55f7fea0b800 5
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr request = resolve
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr sender = email@testdomain.example.net
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: send attr address = example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 35 flush 81
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 35 got 85
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: 0
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: transport
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: transport
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: panel
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: nexthop
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: nexthop
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: recipient
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: recipient
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: flags
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute value: 4096
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: input attribute name: (end)
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: resolve_clnt: `email@testdomain.example.net' -> `example@example.com' -> transp=`panel' host=`example.com' rcpt=`example@example.com' flags= class=default
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: ctable_locate: install entry key email@testdomain.example.net?example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: extract_addr: in: <example@example.com>, result: example@example.com
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: >>> START Client host RESTRICTIONS <<<
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: generic_checks: name=permit_sasl_authenticated
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: generic_checks: name=permit_sasl_authenticated status=0
May 23 13:07:41 blabla postfix/submission/smtpd[9712]: generic_checks: name=reject
```

Why user is not authenticated?
And users get Client host rejected?
How to fix it?

I sent emails via postfix on localhost:

```
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/mail/sender_relay
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/mail/sasl/sasl_passwd
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

Here is fragment of sender_relay:

```
********@gmail.com    [smtp.gmail.com]:587
*******@domenadotes**** [****]:587
```

In place of * is correct data. At least I think so.
sasl_passwd looks like this:

```
email@domenato*****     email@domenadotes*****:1234567890
```

OK. I found. It was typo ^^^ here.

But other question, why it does not work for Outlook users?
Why they have Client host rejected?

Comment: What client did you use, and how did the client authenticate?

Comment: mutt, but mails are sent by postfix
 
    sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = 
        hash:/etc/mail/sender_relay
    smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtp_sasl_password_maps = 
        hash:/etc/mail/sasl/sasl_passwd
    smtp_use_tls = yes
    smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

Sorry, I cannot manage this comment system
Both files sasl_passwd and sender_relay were edited , and compiled by postmap. It works for other hosts for example gmail

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the new content there.